# How to add Chicken exporter in Blender's export menu

Tags: export, blender, panda3d

(Sorry for my inglish)
Hi! I followed the instructions that founded in the chicken's zip but I can't did it.
I extracted the files in C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.63\scripts and in C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.63\scripts but blender don't show the option. Also I didn't found chicken in File\User Preferences\Addons, so I installed using the install addon button. But nothing happend.

What I'm doing wrong?

I'm using Blender 2.63 and chicken R91. I want to export a model to a Panda3d compatible format.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Chicken exporter ( [chicken_exportR91.zip (179.8 kB)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/chicken-export/files/Chicken/Chicken%20R91/) ) was last updated in 2010, which won't work in 2.63 without big changes.

Your best option looks like Panda3d Egg I/O. get the installation zip from: https://code.google.com/p/yabee/ something like https://yabee.googlecode.com/files/YABEE_r12_b263.zip

it seems to be in a folder structure called io_scene_egg, drop this folder and all it contains into `2.63/scripts/addons_contrib`

In preferences -> addons-> enable the 'testing' selector (because the addon is still in development for 2.6+ ). The addon should appear in Import-Export as Import-Export Panda3d EGG Format.

[image]